# Is there a better way to write the logic of this code?

Tags: javascript, php, logic

I will get the `$dados` form Database, each element will have 3 infos `cod`, `nome`, `tree`.

The `tree` will be used to make an tree, visually just like a File Manager, to display this categories (In var `$nome`) and the var `$cod` will be hidden.

The code already works, but I would like to know if is possible to change the "switch" for other code, mainly, because I covered only over the 7nd sub-tree, but if the tree is bigger? This code won't work.

Any ideas?

```
<?php

$dados[0] = [ 'cod'  => 1,
              'nome' => 'Item A',
              'tree' => '1.001'
];

$dados[1] = [ 'cod'  => 2,
              'nome' => 'Item B',
              'tree' => '1.002'
];

$dados[2] = [ 'cod'  => 3,
              'nome' => 'Sub-Item A',
              'tree' => '1.001.001'
];

foreach ( $dados as $v ) {
    $tree  = explode ( '.', $v['tree'] );
    $total = count ( $tree );
    switch ( $total ) {
        case 1:
            $data[$tree[0]] = array (
                'cod'  => $v['cod'],
                'nome' => $v['nome']
            );
            break;
        case 2:
            $data[$tree[0]][$tree[1]] = array (
                'cod'  => $v['cod'],
                'nome' => $v['nome']
            );
            break;
        case 3:
            $data[$tree[0]][$tree[1]][$tree[2]] = array (
                'cod'  => $v['cod'],
                'nome' => $v['nome']
            );
            break;
        case 4:
            $data[$tree[0]][$tree[1]][$tree[2]][$tree[3]] = array (
                'cod'  => $v['cod'],
                'nome' => $v['nome']
            );
            break;
        case 5:
            $data[$tree[0]][$tree[1]][$tree[2]][$tree[3]][$tree[4]] = array (
                'cod'  => $v['cod'],
                'nome' => $v['nome']
            );
            break;
        case 6:
            $data[$tree[0]][$tree[1]][$tree[2]][$tree[3]][$tree[4]][$tree[5]] = array (
                'cod'  => $v['cod'],
                'nome' => $v['nome']
            );
            break;
        case 7:
            $data[$tree[0]][$tree[1]][$tree[2]][$tree[3]][$tree[4]][$tree[5]][$tree[6]] = array (
                'cod'  => $v['cod'],
                'nome' => $v['nome']
            );
            break;
        default:
            break;

    }

}

var_dump ( $data );

?>
```

Comment: Have you tried with a loop? Something from 0 to $total.

Comment: But how I will "increment" the array data KEY?

if it's level 2, how will I make $data[0][1] and not $data[$i] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ( $dados as $v ) {
    $tree  = explode ( '.', $v['tree'] );
                                         // You can think about $p as a pointer
    $p = &$data;                         // now it point to root of array 
    foreach($tree as $i) {
       if (!isset($p[$i])) $p[$i] = '';  // if item is not present, create it
       $p = &$p[$i];                     // change pointer to this item of array, 
                                         // so $p will be $data[$tree[0]], then $data[$tree[1]]...
       }                                 // path finished, this is our aim
       $p = array (                      // add array to a leaf
                'cod'  => $v['cod'],     
                'nome' => $v['nome']
           );
}

var_dump ( $data );
```

Comment: What magic is that?
Lol
Didn't understand how the "$p = array( 'cod' => $v['cod'], 'nome' => $v['nome' );" goes to the right array position.
Even I didn't understanding it, it works flawless.

Comment: I am now from phone. Will write comments tonight

Comment: @Renato Gomes i hope, my comments help you

Comment: I think your comment wasn't saved, because I didn't found any explanation.
But anyway, after awhile I understood what did you do.
You did a genius job.
I'm very grateful for your help.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

@splash58 beat me to it but here is my version:

```
foreach($dados as $v){
    $tree           = explode ( '.', $v['tree'] );
    $arrayElement   = array('cod'  => $v['cod'],'nome' => $v['nome']);
    $arrayHolder    = &$data;
    foreach($tree as $key){
        $arrayHolder[$key] = isset($arrayHolder[$key]) ? $arrayHolder[$key] : array();
        $arrayHolder = &$arrayHolder[$key];
    }
    $arrayHolder = $arrayElement;
}
```